# Handling image load/store in a UIDocument that contains multiple images

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument, nsfilewrapper

I have a simple model object `Location` with a few text items and a `images : [UIImages]?`. `Location` is `Codable` so I store the text bits as JSON and then write the images into the same `FileWrapper`.

My question is how to store the relationship between the image files and the [UIImage] array. The images have to come back in the same order. Is there a way I can hook into Coding so that the array gets replaced by the URLs pointing to the images?

Or alternately, should I always have the images as separate files, say in the cache directory, and replace the [UIImage] with [URL]s

Comment: UIDocument does not require any "Coding" so it's unclear what the issue is. What format you save your document into and restore it from is totally up to you. Take a look at Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/sc2281/Introduction/Intro.html) if you don't understand how to load images from a file wrapper into a UIDocument.

Comment: @matt, this is a question about how to store the relationship between the images and the model object. Is that not clear? I can edit the question.

Comment: No, it's clear. But it's totally up to you how to do it. You get to make up your own file format. You can't _not_ do it "correctly" because you get to define what "correctly" is. Again, I suggest you look at the sample code I linked to. You have not said how the images are to relate to the text in the display of your document, so all this is just hand-waving.

Comment: @matt, it's not clear then. This has nothing to do with storing the files. It has to do with how you turn [UIImage] into something that can be stored in JSON. I will edit it to make this more clear.

Comment: You _don't_ turn UIImage into something that can be stored in JSON. That's why you're using a file wrapper, it's so that you can store the UIImage in the file wrapper. I don't know why you're using JSON but if you're going to use it, the JSON you use is totally up to you. Look at the example I pointed you to! The document knows the _name_ of the image file. That's all you need.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. I've re-written the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Yes but not "in the cache directory"; the images go in the file wrapper. You seem to say the _word_ file wrapper without grasping what a file wrapper _is_. Again, again, again I say: look at Apple's example. You can store the names of the image files as the array; that can be stored as text, JSON, whatever. The format of the file wrapper and how that relates to what you will assemble on loading is totally up to you. I think I've said that several times now. Would it help you if I wrote out the code for a file wrapper that loads several images in order?

Comment: > store the names of the image files as the array
I think this is the actual answer to the question I am asking.

Comment: Okay, I put together some file wrapper code that you can actually run as a test. That will give you the idea of the sort of thing you need to be doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of storing a bunch of image files in a file wrapper, along with an "index" (which I call `list`) of their names in a specific order:

```
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let docurl = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let d = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: [:])
    let imnames = ["manny.jpg", "moe.jpg", "jack.jpg"]
    for imname in imnames {
        let im = UIImage(named:imname)!
        let imfw = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(im, 1)!)
        imfw.preferredFilename = imname
        d.addFileWrapper(imfw)
    }
    let list = try! JSONEncoder().encode(imnames)
    let listfw = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: list)
    listfw.preferredFilename = "list"
    d.addFileWrapper(listfw)
    do {
        try d.write(to: docurl.appendingPathComponent("myFileWrapper"), originalContentsURL: nil)
        print("ok")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

And here's an example of reading that file wrapper by fetching the list and then getting the image files by name in that same order:

```
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let docurl = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let fwurl = docurl.appendingPathComponent("myFileWrapper")
    do {
        let d = try FileWrapper(url: fwurl)
        if let list = d.fileWrappers?["list"]?.regularFileContents {
            let imnames = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: list)
            for imname in imnames {
                if let imdata = d.fileWrappers?[imname]?.regularFileContents {
                    print("got image data for", imname)
                    // in real life, do something with the image here
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("no list")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error); return
    }
```

That prints:

```
got image data for manny.jpg
got image data for moe.jpg
got image data for jack.jpg
```

All you want to do in UIDocument is that same thing, except that UIDocument will write and read the file wrapper for you.